# Get the peak value per cycle

Tags: python, dataframe, date, time, time-series

I would like to get date time include ns in bellow strings.

0      2023-11-02 12:00:00.039\t-201
1      2023-11-02 12:00:00.996\t-201
2      2023-11-02 12:00:01.396\t-198
3      2023-11-02 12:00:01.701\t-86
4      2023-11-02 12:00:02.207\t-196
5      2023-11-02 12:00:03.206\t-105

expected output:
| Date | Time|
| 2023-11-02| 12:00:00.039|
| 2023-11-02| 12:00:00.996|

Comment: I don't understand the link between title and the body of your question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.splitlines()` and `str.split()` and extract the data you want.

```py
import pandas

text = """0 2023-11-02 12:00:00.039\t-201
1 2023-11-02 12:00:00.996\t-201
2 2023-11-02 12:00:01.396\t-198
3 2023-11-02 12:00:01.701\t-86
4 2023-11-02 12:00:02.207\t-196
5 2023-11-02 12:00:03.206\t-105"""

result = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    _, date, time, *_ = line.split()
    result.append([date, time])

print(pandas.DataFrame(result, columns=["Date", "Time"])
      .to_string(index=False, header=True))

#       Date         Time
# 2023-11-02 12:00:00.039
# 2023-11-02 12:00:00.996
# 2023-11-02 12:00:01.396
# 2023-11-02 12:00:01.701
# 2023-11-02 12:00:02.207
# 2023-11-02 12:00:03.206
```

- `a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)` is unpacking, the first element goes in `a`, the second in `b`, etc.
- `_` is a convention meaning that we won't use this variable but the symbol is still necessary to have a correct syntax.
- `*_` is a convention meaning that we don't use the rest of the list.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what is "_" and "*" mean in line 12

Comment: `_, date, time, * = line.split() ` is unpacking.
_ is used to ignore the first element.
* is to the rest of the list

Comment: it've got SyntaxError: invalid syntax in line 12 at "="

Comment: @LuanDang Yes, my bad, change `_, date, time, * = line.split()
    result = (date, time)` with `_, date, time, _ = line.split()
    result.append([date, time])`
I have edited the answer

Comment: Or `_, date, time, *_ = line.split()` is better, more robust.

Comment: it worked, thank you so much!